# NLTK - No module named corpus

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

After installing NLTK and NLTK-DATA with PIP, i run **python** then i type **from nltk.corpus import cmudict** and it works.
But when i wrote a script like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict

d = cmudict.dict()

def nsyl(word):
    return [len(list(y for y in x if y[-1].isdigit())) for x in d[word.lower()]]

print nsyl("hello")
```

I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
File "nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
ImportError: No module named corpus
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show how you are calling the script? I mean it does not make a lot of sense that it works in the interpreter but not when called in a file. I am guessing something's wrong with the environment but this is bizarre.

Comment: python script.py


I will create a virtualenv and retry.

Comment: yep, something must be wrong with the environment. check the python version you installed nltk for and check the python version you are running when typing `python`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your stacktrace: `File "nltk.py", line 1, in <module>`, you have called your file nltk.py. When python searches for a module, it looks in the current directory first, and you have "nltk.py" there. It will import this as nltk, and since your code does not define corpus, it can't find `nltk.corpus`.

To fix this, you should rename your file to something else, say `nltkexperience.py`. Also make sure to remove "nltk.pyc" from your directory if it exists, since this will also be loaded (it's the byte compiled version of your code). After that, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this seems to be a case of version mismatch. If you have multiple versions of Python installed, make sure that the one where you installed NLTK is the one being used when running the script.

As an example, I have Python 2.7, Python 3.3, and Anaconda Python (2.7) installed. My shell defaults to Anaconda (and its pip, e.g.). So when I install something via pip and run it on the command line, it works. At the same time, my Vim is compiled to use the system's Python, and it doesn't see Anaconda's installs/ libraries. So if from within Vim I run Python, I will get an error that the library I installed is not found.

Hope this helps.